# request.querystring

Tags: asp.net

how can i use request.querystring in asp.net.i have a linkbutton and this is in a repeater control.i want to play video for the corresponding link _click.i want to pass a fileID of the corresponding link to a function,how can i do this ?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LnkBtn" 
                OnClick="ButtonShowVideo_Click"><%#Eval("FileName")%>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


Protected Sub ButtonShowVideo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                   ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowVideo.Click
    Repeater1.DataSource = GetSpecificVideo(**here i want to get the fileID**)
    Repeater1.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Function GetSpecificVideo(ByVal i As Object) As DataTable
    'pass the id of the video
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager
                 .ConnectionStrings("UploadConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FileName, FileID,FilePath " + 
             "FROM FileM WHERE FileID = @FileID", connectionString)
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@FileID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
                            DirectCast(i,Integer)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    Return table
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't help you:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LnkBtn" 
                OnClick="ButtonShowVideo_Click"><%#Eval("FileName")%>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

as it will not put FileName into query stirng. Rather use this method:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LnkBtn" 
            CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FileName")%>'
            OnClick="ButtonShowVideo_Click"><%#Eval("FileName")%>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In code behind:

```
Protected Sub ButtonShowVideo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowVideo.Click

    Dim  btn as LinkButton = sender as LinkButton

    if(btn is not null) then
        if(NOT string.IsNullOrEmpty(btn.CommandArgument)) then
                dim vid as integer = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument)
                Repeater1.DataSource = GetSpecificVideo(vid)
                Repeater1.DataBind()
        end if
    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim  btn as LinkButton = sender as LinkButton
in this there is a error "end of statement expected"

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use query string, the button click can do either of the following:

1. Hyperlinks to a page with the designated quertstring to identify the action/entity etc
2. Do a server-side redirect to the page as describe in item 1 above

So where is your issue that you find challenging?